Where are Vagrant symbols (special values) documented?
Both in the documentations of Vagrantfile and in different Vagrantfile files we find symbols like the following:
:id, :ssl, :plaintext, :negotiate :auto, :linux, :windows.
Where are those symbols (special values) documented?
What is the right name for them? Symbols, special variables, special values ...?

can you give a link with an example other than :id ? I've seen ID, e.g. v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096 ... I'm looking for context. Also what provider are you using?

As pointed out by @Menelaos the documentation is in Vagrant GitHub repository in the MDX-files.
A grep of the pattern "\`:[^\` ]*\`" gets all the "special symbols" mentioned in the MDX-files:
$ cd /path/to/vagrant_repo
$ find . -name "*.mdx" -type f -exec grep -iPo "\`:[^\` ]*\`" {} \; | sort | uniq
`:accept_new_or_local_tunnel`
`:accept_new`
`:action`
`:all`
`:always`
`:auto_correct`
`:auto`
`:bootstrap`
`:bridge`
`:bridged`
`:chef_solo`
`:command`
`:continue`
`:datadir`
`:default`
`:detect`
`:disable_warning`
`:disk`
`:dvd.`
`:dvd`
`:each`
`:ecdsa256`
`:ecdsa384`
`:ecdsa521`
`:ed25519`
`:force`
`:halt`
`:hook`
`:id`
`:ip`
`:linux`
`:machine`
`:negotiate`
`:never`
`:pip_args_only`
`:pip`
`:plaintext`
`:provider`
`:rsa`
`:shell`
`:single_run`
`:ssl`
`:type`
`:ui`
`:up`
`:user_data`
`:windows`
`:winrm`

Or a complete grep of all "special symbols" to find all places in the documentation where a "special symbol" is used:
$ find . -name "*.mdx" -type f -exec grep -iPo "\`:[^\` ]*\`" {} \; \
    | sort \
    | uniq \
    | xargs -Ixxx find . -name "*.mdx" -exec grep --color=always -Hne xxx {} \;

./website/content/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.mdx:155:  default value is `:never`. The other options are `:accept_new_or_local_tunnel`,
./website/content/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.mdx:156:  `:accept_new`, or `:always`, which each refer to one of
./website/content/docs/triggers/configuration.mdx:102:  - `:action` - Action triggers run before or after a Vagrant action
./website/content/docs/provisioning/basic_usage.mdx:27:  values are `:each` or `:all`, which makes the provisioner run before each and
...
./website/content/docs/cloud-init/configuration.mdx:49:config.vm.cloud_init :user_data, content_type: "text/cloud-config", path: "config.cfg"
./website/content/docs/cloud-init/configuration.mdx:51:config.vm.cloud_init :user_data do |cloud_init|
./website/content/docs/cloud-init/configuration.mdx:57:However, this is not a requirement. Leaving off `type` will default to `:user_data`.
./website/content/docs/cloud-init/configuration.mdx:60:  cloud-init config. Currently, the only supported `type` is `:user_data`. If a type
./website/content/docs/cloud-init/configuration.mdx:61:  is not defined, it will default to `:user_data`.
./website/content/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.mdx:137:  proper distro. However, this should be changed to `:windows` for Windows guests.
./website/content/docs/vagrantfile/winrm_settings.mdx:18:These settings are only used if you've set your communicator type to `:winrm`.


Intro
For documentation, you’ll want to look at a few places:

Vagrant Documentation: The official Vagrant documentation. They have sections that describe the configuration options and the symbols used. Check out the Vagrantfile Configuration section.

Vagrant Source Code: I think that you should also have a look at the GitHub repository.
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant


Update
Every provider is different and has different placeholders that they provide. So, for example, for virtualbox, you can find the :id parameter described here:

The :id special parameter is replaced with the ID of the virtual
machine being created, so when a VBoxManage command requires an ID,
you can pass this special parameter.

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/faf901402d8e7dd1ff1f814f441894bc34c3bb1c/website/content/docs/providers/virtualbox/configuration.mdx#L114

:@Menelaos: I've read and searched the whole documentation. But I did no find where those are documented. Therefore my question. Searching the source code is not much helpful. Simple question: Where is the meaning of :id explained?

@wolfrevo which provider/vm are you using? virutalbox?

both virtualbox and vmware

Are those placehoders proviced by the providers? Then they are not general/global Vagrant variables?

@wolfrevo they are from the providers. But the only one I found was the example with modifyVm function. Can you give me an example of where you saw the other ones so I can understand better ?

Thanks for the hint. I've grep the source code and found the information.

@wolfrevo Very interested in the details.. If the answer was helpful, please upvote and/or accept!

:@Menelaos: see my answer below.
